# Asp.Net WebApi fiddly URL parsing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-web-api, json-api

I have the following request hitting my api:

```
http://someurl?filter[id]=3f3ca381-d359-4c4f-80bb-ed196788868b%2C0c6c084c-8eb3-45ab-9db8-f2cfe7944020%2C6a0b0ae4-f129-48de-9acd-ddb48f1c6144%2C297fbc6d-878e-4d27-b7cb-2fa5e6d94996%2Cf92e7108-03ad-4ea7-9feb-ceccef19f7b8
```

What is the best way of parsing that?! AFAIK I can't use FromUrl because of the `[id]` part - i would need to be able to use regex i guess.

Is there anything I can use that will parse this URL cleanly - baring in mind it could have multiple filters?

Comment: You can use [GetQueryNameValuePairs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.getquerynamevaluepairs(v=vs.118).aspx) extension method. You'll get `filter.id` as a key and all the rest as value.

Comment: perfect! thanks man